# Downloading csv file from web site using python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python

Iam trying to download a csv file from a website suing python BeautifulSoup .Before clicking on download button I need to make few selection on the screen .This is the site URL(https://apps.who.int/flumart/Default?ReportNo=16).I am new to the Python.Some how through googling I am able to write the below codes.But I got stuck in the code to move ahead.if any one help me it will be helpful:

```
import requests
import html5lib
import bs4
import requests 

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

URL = "http://apps.who.int/flumart/Default?ReportNo=16"

 #"http://www.values.com/inspirational-quotes"
#https://apps.who.int/flumart/Default?ReportNo=16
 r = requests.get(URL) 
 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib') # If this line causes an error, run 'pip install 
  html5lib' 
 or install html5lib
#soup.prettify()
quotes=[]  # a list to store quotes 

 #Filter by:
optionFilterBy = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'ctl_ReportViewer_ctl04_ctl03'}) 
optionFilterBy1 = optionFilterBy.select('selected' option[value] = 1')


 #Select by:
 selectby = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'div id='ctl_ReportViewer_ctl04_ctl05'}) 
 selectby.select('alt')= "Albania"
                    
  #From year 

 Fromyear = soup.find('select', attrs = {'id': 'ctl_ReportViewer_ctl04_ctl07_ddValue'}) 
 Fromyear.select('option[value]= '2020')
                        
  #To year:
  Toyear = soup.find('select', attrs = {'id':'ctl_ReportViewer_ctl04_ctl09_ddValue'}) 
  Toyear.select('option[value]= '2020')
            
  #fro mweek:  
  fromWeek = soup.find('select', attrs = {'id':'ctl_ReportViewer_ctl04_ctl11_ddValue'}) 
  fromWeek.select('option[value]= '1')            
  #To week:
  ToWeek = soup.find('select', attrs = {'id':'ctl_ReportViewer_ctl04_ctl13_ddValue'}) 
  ToWeek.select('option[value]= '52')                            
          
   #Age group by:

  Agegroup = soup.find('select', attrs = {'id':'ctl_ReportViewer_ctl04_ctl15_ddValue'}) 
  Agegroup.select('option[value]= '1') 
          
  # Click view report:
            
   soup.find('id':'ctl_ReportViewer_ctl04_ctl00').click()              
          
   #Down load CSV file form the drop down to save the file in local folder
  soup.find('a', attrs = {'title':'CSV (comma delimited)'}) .click()
```

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. It can't possibly be what you're attempting to run.

Comment: You need to find the link inside the page (i.e href) then you can use requests module, to GET the file.

Comment: In addition, you can't use BeautifulSoup to click on things or select options; it doesn't run any client-side code such as the user interface you're attempting to use here.

Answer (score 1):

Despite from syntax error(s) in your code you've to use selenium for clicking button in website.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
 
# Here Chrome  will be used
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 
# URL of website
url = "https://www.mywebsite.com/"
 
# Opening the website
driver.get(url)

# Here you can get your button by ID and Class too
button = driver.find_element_by_id(ID)
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("slide-out-btn")
 
# clicking on the button
button.click()
```